# How to return Optional String using Java 8 streams

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream, option-type

This code should return the `Optional` String when given `siteUrl` contains key from the predefined list of pairs (or `Optional.empty()` otherwise).

Is there a better way than using `new Pair(null, null)` here? Or maybe change the whole expression?

```
static Optional<String> get(String siteUrl) {
    return Optional.ofNullable(URL_TO_ENVIRONMENT
            .stream()
            .filter(p -> siteUrl.contains(p.getKey()))
            .findFirst().orElse(new Pair(null, null)).getValue());
}

private static final List<Pair> URL_TO_ENVIRONMENT = buildList();

private static List<Pair> buildList() {
    return Arrays.asList(
            new Pair("aaa.mysite.com", "aaa_something"),
            new Pair("bbb.mysite.com", "bbb_something"),
            new Pair("ccc.mysite.com", "ccc_comething"));
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
return URL_TO_ENVIRONMENT.stream()
    .filter(p->siteUrl.contains(p.getKey()))
    .map(Pair::getvalue)
    .findFirst();
```

Do you specifically need the first match?  if you just want any match, use `findAny` instead of `findFirst`.

Comment: wow, this was fast. I actually just need "any match".  thank you, Misha!

Comment: I'd prefer `URL_TO_ENVIRONMENT.stream().filter(p->siteUrl.contains(p.getKey())).findAny().map(Pair::getvalue);`. This way mapping is done outside of the pipeline keeping the pipeline shorter (less stack depth, more chances for inlining, etc.).

Comment: @TagirValeev In my observation, stream-like operations on `Optional` (`map`, `filter`, `flatMap`) tend to throw people off.  So I have a (very) slight preference to avoid them.

Comment: @Tagir Valeev: the total stack depth doesn’t matter as the hotspot still spans the same deep-most stack frames.

Comment: @Holger: sometimes it does matter as it can hit the MaxInlineLevel limit, so you will have something not inlined which would be inlined otherwise. Will try to make some sample benchmark later...

Comment: @Tagir Valeev: Of course, if the map operation exceeds the inline limit, it won’t get inlined, but that’s not different to when you move it out of the operation in the first place. The operation that is likely hot is the filter/findAny loop and at this place, map is not involved.